# Why Is ActionBarSherlock Menu Not Working?

Tags: android, menu, actionbarsherlock, listener, menuitem

Im a noob to android development and i'm a having an issue making the menu item listener work.
When i click on the menu item a toast is supposed to display but nothing happens.  I have the correct imports and have implemented the menuitem listener so i don't understand why it is not working.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
//ABS MenuItem import
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.add(0,1,0,"Gender").setIcon(R.drawable.female_icon).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    menu.add(0,2,0,"Flip").setIcon(R.drawable.flip_icon).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    menu.add(0,3,0,"Preferences").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_example).setOnMenuItemClickListener(RemedyActivity.this).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    menu.add(0,4,0,"Help").setIcon(R.drawable.info).setOnMenuItemClickListener(RemedyActivity.this).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);


    //Side Navigation
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    if (sideNavigationView.getMode() == Mode.RIGHT) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.mode_right).setChecked(true);
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.mode_left).setChecked(true);
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case 1:   
            Toast mToast = Toast.makeText(RemedyActivity.this, "works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            return true;  

        case 2:   
            Toast mToast2 = Toast.makeText(RemedyActivity.this, "works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

EDIT

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            sideNavigationView.toggleMenu();
            break;
        case R.id.mode_left:
            item.setChecked(true);
            sideNavigationView.setMode(Mode.LEFT);
            break;
        case R.id.mode_right:
            item.setChecked(true);
            sideNavigationView.setMode(Mode.RIGHT);
            break;
        case 1:   // id from the xml file
            Toast mToast = Toast.makeText(RemedyActivity.this, "works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            break;   // we handled the click, dont pass it up the chain

        case 2:   // id from the xml file
            Toast mToast2 = Toast.makeText(RemedyActivity.this, "works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            break;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you are trying to show a toast, while using Side navigation.  I've had some issues trying to show a toast with this library in the past.  Try another method to determine whether or not the button is actually working such as NSLog.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            ...
       }
    }
```

instead of `onMenuItemClick`.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but this solution doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you set `return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);` at the end?

Comment: Yes i did.  This is becoming an annoying problem.  Please check my edit.

Comment: I don't understand why your id is `1` and `2`? If it is from xml shouldn't it be like `R.id.1`?

Comment: in onCreateOptionsMenu i set the id as 1,2, etc.  I should still work correct?

Comment: I didn't see where you set these id's (maybe you didn't post it). Anyway, why not try set the id's in xml, see if it works first?

Comment: Ah, I saw it. I never did that, so I really cannot comment whether they'll work.

Answer (score 0):

`return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` might be your problem. According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29), "You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you return false it will not be shown."

If super.onCreateOptionsMenu always returns false (which it probably does), your menu will not show.

Also, you create the toast, but you do not show it. You need to explicitly call `show()`. The current eclipse plugin should give you a warning about that.